# Do the inference rules of the implication-free fragment of classical logic without disjunction elimination form a complete Hilbert calculus for LP?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, nonclassical-logic

**If I take the inference rules for the implication-free fragment of classical logic (listed below) and drop the pair of rules for disjunction elimination, do I get a complete Hilbert calculus for LP (Logic of Paradox)?**

One thing that I am uncertain about, though, is whether pruning away disjunction elimination *without adding back a weaker rule in its place* actually gives me LP instead of some other system.

I also have a higher-level motivation for this question. I like trying to come up with semantics for various propositional logics, but I'm not good at proving or disproving the completeness of a given semantics. I'm trying to pick a simple example of a nonclassical logic so I can get a feel for how to build a completeness argument.

---

Additionally, the original question contains one huge oversight, as Troposphere points out in the comments. LP has *exactly* the same set of tautologies as classical logic. However, it has a different consequence relation. The property that I'm most curious is "completeness" with respect to the *consequence relation*. (I'm not sure whether this property is actually called completeness though.)

---

What follows is an explanation of the question in detail and my attempt to solve the problem myself.

---

I will assume classical logic and ordinary mathematics *in the background* for the purposes of this question.

Let's define the logic of paradox using the following truth table.

```
and          not

  F U T
-------      -----
F F F F     F T
U F U U     U U
T F U T     T F
```

And let disjunction be defined as follows $a \lor b$ = $\lnot(\lnot a \land \lnot b)$.

Logic of paradox has the following sound and complete semantics. This semantics is transparently based on the [semantics of Belnap's four-valued logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-valued_logic#Belnap).

$F$ is $\{0\}$. 
$T$ is $\{1\}$. 
$U$ is $\{0, 1\}$.

The designated truth values are $T$ and $U$.

We can defined the semantics of the primitive operations as follows. Let $\oplus$ be xor or equivalently addition modulo 2. Let $\triangle$ be the symmetric difference. These operations are really defined in $2^{\{0, 1\}}$, but they both preserve set non-emptiness.

$[\lnot x] = \{ 1 \oplus n : n \in [x] \}$ 
$[x \land y] = ([x] \triangle \{1\} \cap [y] \triangle \{1\}) \triangle \{1\} $

Logic of paradox, given the signature $\land, \lor, \lnot$ has the following inference rules (which are also valid in classical logic).

$$ \frac{A}{A \lor B} \;\; \text{is disjunction introduction} $$
$$ \frac{A \land B}{A} \;\; \text{and} \;\; \frac{A \land B}{B} \;\; \text{are conjunction elimination} $$
$$ \frac{A \; \text{and} \; B}{A \land B} \;\; \text{is conjunction introduction} $$
$$ \frac{A}{\lnot\lnot A} \;\; \text{is double negation introduction} $$
$$ \frac{\lnot\lnot A}{A} \;\; \text{is double negation elimination} $$

For my axioms, I will take the following axiom schema (which I **nonstandardly** call the *axiom schema of tautological horn clauses*).

$$ \lnot x_1 \lor \lnot x_2 \lor \cdots \lor \lnot x_n \lor \cdots \lor A \;\; \text{where $A$ is in $\{x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n \}$} $$

I will also take all sentences of the form $\lnot \Gamma_1 \lor \lnot \Gamma_2 \lor \cdots \lor \varphi$ where $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$ is a substitution instance of a primitive inference rule.

The classically-valid pair of rules $\frac{A \lor B \; \text{and}\; \lnot A}{B}$ and $\frac{A \lor B \;\text{and}\; \lnot B}{A}$ is not valid in LP..

I'm pretty sure that the collection of rules above with the disjunction-elimination pair of rules forms a [Hilbert calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_system) for classical logic. The rules are certainly sound with respect to classical logic. I'm pretty sure that these inference rules also guarantee that all the connectives are truth-functional, which gives us classical logic because our background logic is classical logic.

I'm less confident that the rules above **without** disjunction elimination are complete with respect to the intended semantics of LP.

One property that LP has is that all the connectives are $U$-preserving, so if both arguments are $U$, the result will be $U$ as well. Intuitively, this is the thing that knocks out disjunction elimination. Knowing that the negation of a proposition is true in LP is simply not as informative as it would be in classical logic.

One thing that I am uncertain about, though, is whether pruning away disjunction elimination *without adding back a weaker rule in its place* actually gives me LP instead of some other system.

Comment: It's not clear to me how the set of sentences you want to be provable differs from the classical tautologies. Can you give an example of a classical tautology you _don't_ want to be provable, or a formula you want to be provable which is _not_ a classical tautology?

Comment: @Troposphere... yes, that's an important point. I can't believe I missed that. LP has **exactly** the same tautologies as classical logic, although its consequence relation is different. I want to show that the rules I have given are an adequate account of the consequence relation, not just the set of tautologies. This is a big oversight on my part, though. Is "soundness" w.r.t. the consequence relation still called "soundness"?

Comment: I also made a mistake in my above comment. It should say "soundness" and "completeness" not just "soundness".

Comment: Hmm, immediately I would expect that in order to speak about whether a formal system captures a _consequence_ relation, the judgements in the system ought to have a $\vdash$ in them. A usual Hilbert system can do without, because consequence is captured by the object-level $\to$ connective anyway, but if you want to avoid $\to$, I think you should at least make consequence explicit at the _metalevel_.

Comment: @Tropososphere, I was thinking that completeness with respect to the consequence relation would just mean that every true conditional statement (i.e. a proposition with hypotheses) would have a valid conditional proof.